# How to use django loop {% %} to create multiple<div>

Tags: html, django

I have created this code in html file:

```
{% for i in uniindicatorproduct1 %}
    <div id='container'+{{ i }}></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Where uniindicatorproduct1 is actually equal to 2, and I plan to have the output like this:

```
<div id=container1></div> 
<div id=container2></div>
```

Anyone can help me edit this code in order to have the above output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to pass the context to the view that uses that template.

In your views you can add something like this:

```
context = {
    'n': range(insert_number_here),
    ...
    # other context stuff
}

return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for i in n %}
    <div id='container{{ i }}'></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Though you should bear in mind this will start from 0. So in this case you can use django's build-in `forloop.counter` method:

```
{% for i in n %}
    <div id='container{{ forloop.counter }}'></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Also just FYI - there's also a `forloop.counter0` method which starts from 0. `forloop.counter` starts from 1.